# Killing a thread executing a function

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I need to call a function to do some actions. Also, I need to stop it abruptly: I am not looking for a gentle and clean stop because that's the purpose of my test.

Let's assume the call I want to make is the following one:

```
class_1.function_1(arg_1=True)
```

First of all, I cannot use `multiprocessing.Process` (I tried), because for some reason this does not allows me to call properly other function of `class_1`.

So, here is what I did:

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=class_1.function_1, args=(True,))
```

Is runs like a charm, but I have one problem: how can I force stop `thread`? For information, I cannot edit `function_1` nor `class_1`.

Here is some solution I tried, without success:

- calling `_stop()`
- `del thread`

If you have any ideas, I am interested, even without threads.

Thanks!

Comment: "I am not looking for a gentle and clean stop because that's the purpose of my test." What _is_ the purpose of your test? If the thread is doing anything meaningful, and you kill it without cooperation from the thread, then there's no guarantee that shared data upon which the thread operates will be left in a valid/meaningful/useable state. No _real_ program should ever kill a thread. If it's time for a thread to die, the program should _ask_ the thread to clean up and kill itself.

Comment: You can only ask  a thread nicely to exit (via some sort of flag variable the thread checks periodically). A [`Process`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) can be killed via `.terminate()` which sends an actual os level terminate [signal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html). It may be worth a question on finding out why `process` wasn't working for you. TLDR; with specifically threads: you can't

Answer (score 1):

you can use `python-worker` [link](https://pypi.org/project/python-worker/)

```
from worker import worker

@worker
def my_function():
    ...

my_worker = my_function()

## put some code

my_worker.abort()
```

`my_function` will automatically run as a thread and `my_worker.abort()` will stop it immediately

Comment: I see you are the author for `python-worker`. It looks like a nice project - but why the 5 different attempts to call `ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc` (which is the core call that would answer this question). Does the parametert need to the call really varies "at random"? Or does it depend on the Op. System? 
Anyway, even you have to make fice attempts on the abort call, it would be more elegant to use a for-loop there - I'd make a patch for that, but I would like to know why the differing ways to get the 1st parameter. It would be nice to have that answer as comments in the code.

Comment: yes. because different python version and operating system have different way to terminate it. older version use `native_id` and newer version use `ident`. Yes depends on OS. Linux requires fixed `ctypes` type but on windows it doesn't matter. So I run it with trial, to make sure it completed not really 5 times.

for the differing ways, I thought it will be more flexible if you want to use `@worker` directly or with some params in it `@worker(*some_args)`